# Can I force MVC to get a new page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using code like this:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 86400, VaryByParam = "none")] 
public ActionResult Index() {
}
```

Everything works well BUT there are times when I would like to force MVC to get a new page when I do a redirect to the index page using:

```
RedirectToAction("index", "home");
```

Is this possible? Is there some way that I can invalidate the cache?

Comment: Don't know about invalidating the cache, but you could maybe redirect to a different action if you don't want the cached result? `public ActionResult IndexNoCache() { }`

Comment: Richard - But then the problem is that when I go back to the index I'll still get the same cached page :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
HttpResponse.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/Home");
```