# Caching my action method on server, will allow unauthorized users to access related action methods

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, caching

I have the following action method with a cache on server setting:

```
[CheckUserPermissions(Action = "", Model = "Admin")]
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "short", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server, VaryByHeader = "X-Requested-With")]
public ActionResult SystemInfo(int page = 1,bool forTechAudit=false)
{
```

And the `CheckUserPermision` action filter will return unauthorized message to the users who do not have the required permissions as follows:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class CheckUserPermissionsAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
//code goes here
// IF user is not authorized then ….
var viewResult = new ViewResult();
viewResult.ViewName = "~/Views/Errors/_Unauthorized.cshtml";
filterContext.Result = viewResult; }}

base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);}}}
```

Now if a user access the `SystemInfo` action method and he is not authorized he will get `/_Unauthorized.cshtml` view, but if another user who is authorized and calls the `SystemInfo` action method he will get the `*/_Unauthorized.cshtml*` view also.

Also if an authorized user access the `SystemInfo` first, then a unauthorized user will be able to see call the action method and see the cached result? and even the current login username will be cached and the users will see others username on their sessions.

Can anyone advice how I can overcome this issue? Currently I changed the cache location to be on the client instead of server which temporary solve the issue, but I need to cache the action method on the server. I am thinking of passing the loginusername to my action method - any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

See the following questions:

- [MVC3 custom outputcache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590183/mvc3-custom-outputcache)
- [Using ASP.NET MVC OutputCache while varying View content based on whether user is authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3444245/using-asp-net-mvc-outputcache-while-varying-view-content-based-on-whether-user-i)
- [Why can't I combine [Authorize] and [OutputCache] attributes when using Azure cache (.NET MVC3 app)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682635/why-cant-i-combine-authorize-and-outputcache-attributes-when-using-azure-ca)
- [OutputCache and Authorize filters in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731959/outputcache-and-authorize-filters-in-mvc3)

I read through these questions, and it seems the `OutputCacheAttribute` works well with the `AuthorizeAttribute`. So maybe you should check how the `AuthorizeAttribute` handles the caching, and implement that in your actionfilter.

Personally I liked this approach: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60403/how-does-stack-overflow-do-caching/60406#60406

---

Edit: view the source of the `AuthorizeAttribute` [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs), and take a look the `OnAuthorization` function. Maybe it helps.

Comment: but your last link mentioned that stack overflow does not use cache for login users!!

Comment: and as a temporary solution, if i chnage all the cache location to be on the client instead of being on the server , will this remove the risk of having unauthorized users accessing sensitive cached data?

Comment: Yes I know the data is not cached for authenticated users. But for a site like StackOverflow that's even better because the users see the newest data. It depends on the purpose of your website. It indeed does not fix your problem, but I thought it was an interesting approach to caching. As for the client site, you probably have problem when a user uses your application on a public computer, logs off, and the authenticated data is still cached. You should test it.

Comment: but if the data is cached on the client and the user logoff, then other users who use the public computer should not be able to see the cached data unless they login to the system,, i think this should be the case..